# Vagrant + Virtualbox cannot `sharedfolder add` during VM provisioning

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, automation, vagrant

I am automating the provisioning of a custom Ubuntu Server 22.10 (custom-built with `packer`) in Virtualbox using `vagrant`. During provisioning I get the following error:

```
2023-01-12T07:39:14.671+0200 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-vagrant_4.1.0: 2023/01/12 07:39:14 [ERROR] There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["sharedfolder", "add", "cd8bca46-158a-40ad-8928-2a0eefecce19", "--name", "vagrant", "--hostpath", "/home/cyau/kubernetes-cluster"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: fatal error: RTR3Init: VERR_NO_TRANSLATION: timestamp=2023-01-12T07:39:14.671+0200
```

The above logs are from Terraform, but I have tried with a simple `vagrant up` with the same results, both on Virtualbox 7.0 and Virtualbox 6.1.

---

`vagrant`: 2.3.4

`Virtualbox`: 6.1.38_Ubuntur153438

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

`terraform`: 1.3.6

---

Vagrantfile:

```
private_key_path = ENV.fetch("private_key_path", "/home/cyau/.ssh/virtual_id_ed25519")
virtual_machine_image = ENV.fetch("virtual_machine_image", "ubuntu-22.10-live-server-amd64")
# virtual_machine_index = ENV.fetch("virtual_machine_index", "")
ip_base = ENV.fetch("ip_base", "192.168.56")
ip_offset = ENV.fetch("ip_offset", "11").to_i
#count_index = ENV.fetch("count_index", "").to_i

cluster_name = ENV.fetch("cluster_name", "kubernetes-cluster")

node_name = ENV.fetch("node_name", "worker")
node_cpus = ENV.fetch("node_cpus", "1").to_i
node_memory = ENV.fetch("node_memory", "2").to_i
node_count = ENV.fetch("node_count", "2").to_i

VAGRANT_DISABLE_VBOXSYMLINKCREATE=1

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.ssh.insert_key = false
    config.ssh.private_key_path = private_key_path

    (1..node_count).each do |i|
        config.vm.define "#{node_name}-#{i}" do |node|
            node.vm.box = virtual_machine_image
            node.vm.box_url = "file://../packer-vmis/#{virtual_machine_image}.box"
            node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "#{ip_base}.#{i + ip_offset}"
            node.vm.hostname = "#{node_name}-#{i}"
            node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
                v.memory = node_memory
                v.cpus = node_cpus
            end            
            node.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
                ansible.playbook = "./roles/k8s.yml"
                #Redefine defaults
                ansible.extra_vars = {
                    k8s_cluster_name: cluster_name,   
                    # The below are repeated because of Ansible configuration, consider refactoring                 
                    k8s_master_admin_user:  "vagrant",
                    k8s_master_admin_group: "sudo",
                    k8s_node_admin_user:  "vagrant",
                    k8s_node_admin_group: "sudo",
                    k8s_master_apiserver_advertise_address: "#{ip_base}.#{i + ip_offset}",
                    k8s_master_node_name: "#{node_name}-#{i}",
                    k8s_node_public_ip: "#{ip_base}.#{i + ip_offset}"
                }                
            end
        end
    end
end
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Vagrantfile

private_key_path = ENV.fetch("private_key_path", "/home/cyau/.ssh/virtual_id_ed25519")
virtual_machine_image = ENV.fetch("virtual_machine_image", "ubuntu-22.10-live-server-amd64")
ip_base = ENV.fetch("ip_base", "192.168.56")
ip_offset = ENV.fetch("ip_offset", "11").to_i

cluster_name = ENV.fetch("cluster_name", "kubernetes-cluster")

node_name = ENV.fetch("node_name", "worker")
node_cpus = ENV.fetch("node_cpus", "1").to_i
node_memory = ENV.fetch("node_memory", "2").to_i
node_count = ENV.fetch("node_count", "2").to_i

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.ssh.private_key_path = private_key_path

  (1..node_count).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "#{node_name}-#{i}" do |node|
      node.vm.box = virtual_machine_image
      node.vm.box_url = "file://../packer-vmis/#{virtual_machine_image}.box"
      node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "#{ip_base}.#{i + ip_offset}"
      node.vm.hostname = "#{node_name}-#{i}"
      node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = node_memory
        v.cpus = node_cpus
      end

      # Add this line to disable the shared folder creation
      node.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

      # Uncomment the Ansible provisioning once basic Vagrant setup works fine
      # node.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      #   ansible.playbook = "./roles/k8s.yml"
      #   ansible.extra_vars = {
      #     k8s_cluster_name: cluster_name,
      #     # ... (previous configurations)
      #   }
      # end
    end
  end
end
```

In this updated Vagrantfile, I've added the line node.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true to disable the default shared folder creation. This should prevent the specific shared folder error you encountered with VBoxManage.

Now, when you run vagrant up, the shared folder creation should be skipped, and you can focus on testing the basic Vagrant setup without Ansible provisioning. If the basic setup works fine, uncomment the Ansible provisioning section to continue with your original setup.